# Embedding (possibly approximate) of category into topological space (as a category of open sets of this space)?

Tags: category-theory, topological-vector-spaces, graph-embeddings

I am thinking about embedding of categories into topological spaces (or even manifolds).

I have found 2 connections:

1. one can construct the nerve/groupoid from a category and then use homotopy hypothesis to find the space for this groupoid. It is the representation of category that preserves the homotopical properties only.
2. I have found this article "[Embedding of a free cartesian-closed category into the category of sets](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022404996001375)" by Djordje Čubrić, where he embeds $\mathrm{CCC}$ into the category of sets, and despite the fact that this is not a topological space as the category of open sets, but still I'd like something along these lines.

From the one side there is rich culture on efforts to embed graphs into manifolds (e.g. in the deep learning). From the other side there are some scarce (and old) results about embeddings of categories I mentioned.

Maybe someone suggest some topics, ideas, research efforts that advance those embeddings?

Comment: To me, it is unclear what you are asking, specifically.

Comment: Do you want a fully faithful functor $Cat \to Top$?

Comment: More specifically, I would like fully faithful functor from the category of contexts (as understood in the categorical approach to HoTT) to the space considered as category (whose objects are open sets and morphisms - mappings between them).

Comment: I have shy intuition that it could explain embedding of theory inside the vector space formed by all the possible points of one layer of neural network.

Comment: I mentioned approximate because it can be that fully faithful functor may not exist. Then the practice would require (practice never accepts answer "no") finding approximate one. But it may be possible that it the theme of separate question.

Comment: Ok, I tried, but I have no idea what you want :)

Comment: Its simple. Assume that I have concrete HoTT theory, e.g. about penguins, Tweety etc. One can construct category of contexts, that is the categorical representation of this theory, this is very concrete category: types in contexts are objects, etc.

Comment: Then I ask for all topological spaces (each one can be considered as category whose objects are open sets of space and morphisms are mappings or subset relations) and all functors from particular cat of contexts so, that functor to each is faithful.

Comment: Each such topological space in turn can be mapped to subset system of n-dimensional vector space, which is made from n-dimensional points, each one corresponding to some activation of n-neuron layer. Thats ir! Theory encoded into NN layer.

Comment: A bit down-to-earh approach a la "Topos and stacks of deep neural networks" which is overwhelming paper.